# Transition using ng-animate not working in 1.2.16

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to recreate the following transitions using ng-animate in angular v1.2.16 instead of v1.1.4 (used in fiddle).

If you update the angular lib in the fiddle to 1.2.16 the transitions no longer work. Why do they no longer work? 
link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/angularjs_de/dxQqm/

html

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-animate="'repeat'">{{item}}</li>
```

css

```
.repeat-enter-setup, .repeat-leave-setup {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  -ms-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  -o-transition:all linear 0.3s;
  transition:all linear 0.3s;
}

.repeat-enter-setup { opacity:0; }
.repeat-enter-setup.repeat-enter-start {  opacity:1; }

.repeat-leave-setup { opacity:1;  }
.repeat-leave-setup.repeat-leave-start { opacity:0; }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dxQqm/165/ v1.2.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular changed the way animations work in 1.2+.
Animation is now a separate module that needs to be added.

There is a very nice guide on 1.2+ animations found here:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Edit: In that link they also talk about what has changed from 1.1.5 to 1.2 it will help you understand the changes.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

  $scope.replaceItem = function() {
    $scope.items.shift();
    $scope.items.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000));
  };    
}]);
```

Solution in fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dxQqm/166

Comment: I've manually added the ngAnimate module yet still the ng-repeat isn't animated

Comment: I've updated your fiddle to have the animations work in 1.2.6 
http://jsfiddle.net/dxQqm/166/